# Leaving a process running using screen without sleeping

Tags: matlab, ssh

I connect to a server using ssh, and then created a screen using the "screen" command.
Then I run a Matlab script using: "matlab < NameofFile.m", and Matlab starts running the script.

I log out the screen (with Ctl+a+d) and disconnect from the server. Then, when I connect to the server again and check the screen I created appears that Matlab is runnig, but when I use the command "top", the information provided indicates that the process I left running in the screen is in sleep mode (S).

How can I leave a process running using a screen in such a way that when I leave the screen, the process is properly running (ie, indicates "R" when I use the command "top")?

Thanks in advance for any help you could provide.

Comment: Have you tried running the process in background: `matlab < NameOfFile.m &`?

Comment: Why is a sleep state unexpected?  Sleep is a normal process state, occurring whenever the process waits for something.  It's still in the ready queue, and will run it's waiting is satisfied.  So at I'm not surprised it's sleeping.  That said, maybe your script is completely CPU-bound, like: ( while :; do :; done ) & ps e $! -- which will always show "R" -- so you expect an R always.  nohup matlab < script.m & keeps it alive even after terminal disconnect (which isn't happening here: screen is managing the terminal session, and as far as matlab knows, the screen is still connected).

Comment: Shai: I have used "matlab < NameOfFile.m &", but the result is the same.

Comment: bishop: the script has several while/for loops and I am expecting to be running for a long time. When I check the process using "top", it says that the CPU is 100%, and being in sleeping mode (S), but the script does not wait for any external input or something similar. Is that normal or I should use "nohup matlab < script.m &"?

Comment: Short answer: probably normal and your script is running to completion.  However, please post some sample top output. Use top -d .01 -pPID (replace PID with the actual process ID) to gauge if it's sleeping for a long time or hitting the CPU in contention with another process.  I suspect that other matlab computations are contending with yours. If you have prstat or latencytop commands, you can look at the LAT for each (eg, prstat -m 2).  Finally, use the @bishop moniker so that I get notified of your comment. :)

Comment: @bishop: thanks for the answer, actually i got confused about the symbol S (sleeping), but it was actually running the whole time. you were right.

Comment: @gus: Great, glad it's solved. I added a formal answer for posterity.  Please up-vote and accept! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See thread for discussion, answered here for posterity.

Sleep is a normal process state, occurring whenever a process waits for something (usually I/O).  The process remains in the ready queue and will run when it's done waiting.  So I'm not surprised your process sleeping.

That said, your script could be *completely* CPU-bound, like: `( while :; do :; done ) & ps e $!` -- which will always show `R`.  Completely CPU-bound processes are *extremely* rare -- they really have to output something at some point to be useful, and such I/O will move them to sleeping.  Moreover, even if they don't output for a long time, there are usually other processes vying for the CPU, which the kernel will force with preemption.  (Unless you have a very specific `nice` level or a very specific kernel configuration that lets your non-output generating CPU script completely hog the CPU.  Which is a really, really rare scenario.)

If you want to better monitor the state changes, you can use `top -d .01 -pPID` (replace PID with the actual process ID).  That let's you gauge if it's sleeping for a long time or hitting the CPU in contention with another process.  If you have `prstat` or `latencytop` commands, you can look at the `LAT` for each (eg, `prstat -m 2`), which will tell you how much contention that process experiences.  The closer to 0, the less contention.

Answering the general question of "How can I leave a process running", one could do: `nohup matlab < script.m &`.  That keeps the process alive even after terminal disconnect.  But using `screen` means you don't need to do that, because `screen` manages the terminal session, and as far as `matlab` knows, the screen is still connected.